# How can I popup a hidden view with a button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

i have a hidden view with two buttons and i need to pop him up when i click on the other button on the screen
this is the code of the button .

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUp") as! PopUpViewController
self.addChild(popOverVC)
popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
popOverVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Comment: Do you want to present your view as a popover or just unhide it?

Comment: Can you clarify more on what you want to achieve?